# python 3.6 ascii codec error in urllib request

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to download picture from website with my python script, but every time i use georgian alphabet in url it gets error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters"

here is my code:

```
import os
import urllib.request

def download_image(url):
    fullfilename = os.path.join('/images', 'image.jpg')

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)


download_image(u'https://example.com/media/სდასდსადადსაფა_8QXjrbi.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use **requests** library in your example which deals with utf-8 characters.

Here is the code:

```
import requests

def download_image(url):

    request = requests.get(url)
    local_path = 'images/images.jpg'

    with open(local_path, 'wb') as file:  
        file.write(request.content)

my_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/ერეკლე_II_ბავშვობის_სურათი.jpgw/459px-ერეკლე_II_ბავშვობის_სურათი.jpg'

download_image(my_url)
```